# JQuery Click by code from another click

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this code:

```
<label style="display: inline; " for="default">
<img class="ful" src="http://www.mysite.com/default.png" />
<input style="display:none" id="default" name="selected" type="radio" value="template" onclick="SubmitValue();" />
</label>
```

I need to trigger the onclick or click on the code above but clicking on another anchor elsewhere.

Can this be done?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From jQuery you would just say

```
$("#default").click();
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/SHYDe/

There's an example of this on the [jQuery `.click()` doco page](http://api.jquery.com/click/).

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
$('#default').click();
```

using jQuery

Answer (score 1):

```
$(wrappedobject).trigger('click');
```

as far as i know

http://api.jquery.com/trigger/

Answer (score 1):

Do you mean :

```
$("#anchorId").click(function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  $("#default").trigger("click");
});
```